# MySQL Query Error 1054

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this **MySQL** query

```
SELECT count( * ) AS total
FROM `orders` o, `orders_status` s, `orders_status_history` osh
LEFT JOIN `orders_total` ot ON ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
WHERE o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id
AND osh.orders_id = o.orders_id
AND s.language_id = '5'
AND s.orders_status_id = '6'
AND ot.class = 'ot_total'
```

getting this error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'o.orders_id' in 'on clause'
```

My table schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `last_modified` datetime default NULL,
  `orders_status` int(5) NOT NULL default '0',
  `orders_date_finished` datetime default NULL,
  `comments` text,
  `currency` char(3) default NULL,
  `currency_value` decimal(14,6) default NULL,
  `invoice_number` varchar(100) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`orders_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=8419 ;
```

And I can't understand where the error comes from. Any ideas?

Comment: I've made a correction in the query and the error. I am sorry. I was using a keyword as a alias but there is still an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/join.html):

> Previously, the comma operator (`,`) and `JOIN` both had the same precedence, so the join expression `t1, t2 JOIN t3` was interpreted as `((t1, t2) JOIN t3)`. Now `JOIN` has higher precedence, so the expression is interpreted as `(t1, (t2 JOIN t3))`. This change affects statements that use an `ON` clause, because that clause can refer only to columns in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes interpretation of what those operands are.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (i1 INT, j1 INT);
> CREATE TABLE t2 (i2 INT, j2 INT);
> CREATE TABLE t3 (i3 INT, j3 INT);
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,1);
> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1,1);
> INSERT INTO t3 VALUES(1,1);
> SELECT * FROM t1, t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
> ```
>
> Previously, the `SELECT` was legal due to the implicit grouping of `t1,t2` as `(t1,t2)`. Now the `JOIN` takes precedence, so the operands for the `ON` clause are `t2` and `t3`. Because `t1.i1` is not a column in either of the operands, the result is an `Unknown column 't1.i1' in 'on clause'` error. To allow the join to be processed, group the first two tables explicitly with parentheses so that the operands for the `ON` clause are `(t1,t2)` and `t3`:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM (t1, t2) JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
> ```
>
> Alternatively, avoid the use of the comma operator and use `JOIN` instead:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
> ```
>
> This change also applies to statements that mix the comma operator with `INNER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, and `RIGHT JOIN`, all of which now have higher precedence than the comma operator.

Answer (score 2):

You have an `OR` as your table alias for your orders table. You need to change the table alias name.

```
SELECT count( * ) AS total
FROM `orders` o , `orders_status` s, `orders_status_history` osh
LEFT JOIN `orders_total` ot ON ot.orders_id = or.orders_id
WHERE o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id
AND osh.orders_id = or.orders_id
AND s.language_id = '5'
AND s.orders_status_id = '6'
AND ot.class = 'ot_total'
```

You should also change your JOIN syntax

```
SELECT count( * ) AS total
FROM `orders` o 
LEFT JOIN `orders_status` s
    ON o.order_status = s.orders_status_id
LEFT JOIN `orders_status_history` osh
    ON osh.orders_id = o.orders_id  
LEFT JOIN `orders_total` ot 
    ON ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
WHERE s.language_id = '5'
    AND s.orders_status_id = '6'
    AND ot.class = 'ot_total'
```

Comment: I've made a correction in the query and the error. I am sorry. I was using a keyword as a alias but there is still an error. (I just tried to change the alias with 'or'  from ORders but I forgot that it's a keyword)

Comment: @Itehnological please check my second version of the query

Answer (score 1):

Or is a mysql keyword! replace it with something else, e.g _or & try again!