# When is CROSS JOIN useful?

Tags: mysql, sql, cross-join

When I read the documentation about `CROSS JOIN`, I wondered, because it seems pointless. You can do that using just a comma `,`. I tested it (several times) and the results of these queries were exactly the same:

```
// one
SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2

// two
SELECT * FROM table1, table2
```

Anyway, I want to know: is there any logical reason for using `CROSS JOIN` instead of `,`?

Comment: _This is a conservative extension if we consider each comma in a list of table_reference items as equivalent to an inner join._

Comment: Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  The two are syntactically equivalent, but explicit joins are clearer and more powerful.

Comment: Beware also that, since MySQL 5.0.12, the implicit join comma `,` operator has lower precedence than explicit joins (including `CROSS JOIN`).  This can effect the outcome of queries which join tables without explicit precedence from use of parentheses `()`—e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10556505).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the simple rule of never using commas in the `from` clause and always using explicit `join` syntax, there is a good reason.  The issue is the difference between these two queries:

```
select *
from table1, table2;
```

and

```
select *
from table1 table2;
```

These do very different things, and it can be rather hard to spot the difference (particularly in a more complicated query).  If you never have commas in the `FROM` clause, then your queries will be easier to read and less prone to typos and other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following...

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT * FROM my_table, my_table x;

SHOW WARNINGS; (reformatted for clarity)

select test.my_table.id AS id
     , test.my_table.car_id AS car_id
     , test.my_table.car_model AS car_model
     , test.my_table.car_features AS car_features
     , test.x
     . id AS id
     , test.x.car_id AS car_id
     , test.x.car_model AS car_model
     , test.x.car_features AS car_features 
  from test.my_table 
  join test.my_table x
```

Comment: @eggyal My point is that a comma join materializes as an explicit join. There are no errors ; this is exactly what MySQL generates (just reformatted a little)